# Unknown word and strange use of えと

Tags: grammar, definitions, sentence-final-particles

Take the sentence:

> バッサリいこうぜ！うっとうしいだろ[長]{なげ}えとよ。

The first, from context,  I think means "You're gonna get a haircut!" I can't find バッサリ in the dictionary, though. The second probably says "It's seems irritating at that length." I'm not sure how the filler えと functions here. Especially with the particle よ.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying edit. Unfortunately there was no furigana on it in the text. So it's my best guess.

Comment: This isn't 長 followed by えと; 長い has a very colloquial pronunciation なげえ, and then とよ follows that.

Comment: @Nothingatall Please write it in an answer.

Comment: @変幻出没 I can't answer it fully.

Comment: @johnnd Is this from the same manga as your other question? If so, may I ask its name?

Comment: @Nothingatall what are your problems? ばっさり is to be found there (http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/177459/meaning/m0u/%E3%83%90%E3%83%83%E3%82%B5%E3%83%AA/  ) , よ is ending particle and と is quoting particle.

Comment: The と in 「長いと(うっとうしい)」 is not a quotative particle. It's a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle) -> See #❷-2 http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/154670/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%A8/.

Comment: So,  better translation "Seems like the length is annoying too."? I wish I knew. It's from a text transcription from a friend who knows I'm trying to learn the language but is reluctant to tell me her source.

Comment: I used jisho.org.

Comment: 「(髪が)長いと、(=長かったら、)うっとうしいだろう。」It's annoying if (your hair) is long, isn't it? って意味です。

Comment: So, you're saying the とよ combination requests confirmation similar to な?

Comment: @変幻出没 I just don't know how to explain it. I do understand the sentence.

Comment: @johnnd No. だろ, rather than (と)よ, requests confirmation. I think the よ is closer to さ than な. See [#❷ 間投助詞「さ」](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/84242/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%95/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[長]{なげ}え is a colloquial, masculine and a bit vulgar way of pronouncing [長]{なが}い.
(Compare: うるさい→うるせえ, しらない→しらねえ, たべたい→たべてえ)

The と in 長いと is a 接続助詞(conjunctive particle), meaning "if~~" or "when~~".

So the なげえと(長いと) here means "If (your hair is) long" or "When (your hair is) long".

> バッサリいこうぜ！うっとうしいだろ長えとよ。(≒長いとうっとうしいだろ。)
>   Let's cut it short. (Because) It's annoying if it's long, isn't it?

And I think the よ at the end is #❷ 間投助詞 -２ in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226011/meaning/m0u/%E3%82%88/)

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation.  Being very new to the language,  things like colloquial pronunciations trip me up easily.
Oh,  so いっこう is the "completely"  definition here. I was somehow thinking of the verb to go.

Comment: @johnnd Oh the いこう(ぜ) is 行こう, the volitional form of the verb 行く. Literally "Let's go~~." Here it's like "Let's do~~."

Comment: OK,  so then バッサリ implies a short haircut?

Comment: @johnnd Yes, バッサリ/ばっさり(+と) is an adverb for cutting something (eg. hair, bough, budget etc.) off short, with a single stroke, or drastically. Here it indicates cutting your hair short (decisively/drastically)

Comment: We call both interjectional usage and filler one "間投助詞" but on a second thought we should distinguish them. Anyway, these usages of よ are slang in Standard Japanese.