# What is the meaning of this Japanese sentence?

Tags: translation

The scene: A boy plays a ghita on the street to earn money then a bunch of yakuzas show up. They steal his ghita and say:

Yakuza1: "わしらのしま で. 何 勝手しとんじゃい" (This is our turf. You think you can do whatever you like?)

Yakuza2:"ショバ代払えね ならよォー 足りねー分は"

The yakuza 2 being hit by someone right after saying the sentence.

Does the sentence of the yakuza 2 means " If you pay for protection, you don't have enough minute..." Or " You must pay us money for protection. If you don't have enough minute...?

Comment: Could you explain in more detail which parts you understand and which you don't? Your translation is giving some hints, but it appears to be a loose translation, so it's not clear if you understood the individual parts of the sentence, like 払えね or よォー or 足りねー etc. (Maybe you could also include more context or a picture.)

Comment: I just edited. I know the part "ショバ代払えね" but I don't know the rest. I think 足りねー分 is 足りない分

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61571/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ショバ代払えね ならよォー 足りねー[分]{ぶん}は

The [分]{ぶん} is not "minute" ([分]{ふん/ぷん}) but "amount", "part".

払えねなら (払えねーなら) means 払え**ない**なら, "if you can't pay".

You're right that 足りねー分 is 足りない分, literally "the amount that's not enough" → the rest of the payment, remaining bill, or shortfall, deficit.

"If you can't pay for protection, the remaining amount..." [the sentence is cut off]

Comment: Is 「よォー 」 the particle 「よ」, like in 「そうだよ」?

Comment: @Mauro, そうですね, it's the particle よ, used as a bit rough, masculine filler(間投助詞), rather than as a sentence-end particle(終助詞).   https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52582/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30050/9831